# Forest canopy structure

Tags: remote-sensing, forest, biomass

Optical remote sensing technology is commonly used for forest biomass estimation. The NDVI is used to define greenness. But how can we tell about biomass after capture only canopy area from above? Is it only outermost layer, right? Can only NDVI represent the all biomass of tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an expert in this field but I found this in quick Google search:
[image]

Reference: https://doi.org/10.2307/1942049

I think from line 8 the answer to your question begins.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).